# Cannot See Public Variable in Sidebar of Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kD47gUJO7jA) tutorial to code a VR game in Unity. When I got to the scripting, I ran into an issue. I could not see variables in the Inspector sidebar. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Hello : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    public AudioClip clip;
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public Transform gunBarrelTransform;

    void Start ()
    {
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        audioSource.clip = clip;
    }

    void Update (){
        if (OVRInput.Get (OVRInput.Button.SecondaryHandTrigger)) {
            audioSource.Play ();
            RaycastGun ();
        }

    }
    private void RaycastGun()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast (gunBarrelTransform.position, 
gunBarrelTransform.forward, out hit)) {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag ("Cube")) {
                Destroy (hit.collider.gameObject);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even when I remove the [SerializeField] it does not work. Does anybody know why the variables aren't showing up? Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Please post the screenshot of the "sidebar"

Comment: It must be enought if you declare your variables as public, they should be in the inspector window.

Comment: If you don't see your variable in the inspector, you may have a compilling error in one of your scripts. Can you check the console?